# iOS custom keyboard on iPad

Tags: ios, uiview, keyboard, uitextfield

I'm building an iPad app witch will use a numeric keyboard. The numeric keyboard for the iPad is really huge, all i need is something smaller, something like the decimal keyboard for the iphone.

If i use the default one, half the screen gets covered with keys i dont need. I know i can move the textfields out of the way but it is such a waste of screen space.

So i tried building a custom UIView with no button for start and setting the textfield.inputview  to my custom UIView. 
 The only thing i got is that my custom view is displayed like/in place of/the stock keyboard and the only thing i can change is the height of the custom view.

How could i build a sort of custom keyboard that apple will accept and works with the textfields.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what i was looking for. The answer is UIPopover. I managed to build a custom keypad inside a uipopover.

Here's a good tutorial for the uipopover: 
http://www.appcoda.com/uiactionsheet-uipopovercontroller-tutorial/

And here's some more info on what you have to do to make it work: 
http://iphone-bitcode.blogspot.fr/2011/12/custom-number-pad-on-ipad.html